# Error al guardar un modelo en Django. ¿Cómo hago para que django guarde un model con otra id si esta ya existe?

Tags: django, postgresql

Estoy usando `Django`, y tengo guardado algún modelo para probar desde `django`, pero también tengo creados desde el administrador de `postgresql`.

Al insertar un nuevo modelo, me ha dado error de integridad ya que la **ID** ya estaba en uso.

Hay alguna opción para que `Django` asigne siempre que crea un modelo, un nuevo **id**, en vez de dar error?

Si no, puede darse el caso que se carguen datos desde fuera de `django`, copias de seguridad o lo que sea, y ya no se puedan hacer inserciones desde `django`, ya que ha perdido la referencia de las **ids** libres.

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas una aplicación en Django, te crea una carpeta llamada *migrations*, no tengo en mente ahora mismo un ejemplo claro a mano de como mostrarte, pero si te colocaré 2 fuentes en donde puedes ver cómo manejar las migraciones. Es importante saber un poco de esto, ya que con las migraciones puedes hacer a que por defecto al momento de crearse un objeto nuevo tenga un valor específico, entre otras.

https://realpython.com/django-migrations-a-primer/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/

Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras, antes de salvar en el método `clean()` o cuando salvas en el método `save()`, puedes obtener el objeto
`ultimo = Modelo.objects.all().last()`
`self.id = ultimo.id + 1`